# Select Radio Button With Java Script getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server, plsql

By using javaScript or jquery I need to change a radio button, every time that the customer click on a image, the event call a java script function.

this is a portion of the code:

PLSQ Server AND HTML

```
htp.p(' function js_edit_cont_rec(cnk,ctk,cnc,cntk,cnrk,ln,fn,mini,es,maxs,tz,ca,hrs,er,sts) { ');
htp.p('  document.getElementById("cont_title").innerHTML  = "Edit Contact Information" ');
htp.p('document.getElementById("status_element").style.visibility="visible";');
htp.p('document.getElementById("sc2").checked= true;');
```

Then I have within the form the radio button, I am using css in order to create a row within the form

PLSQL SERVER AND HTML

```
htp.p('<div id="status_element" class= "rowElem noborder" style="visibility:hidden" ><label>Status:</label>');
htp.p('<div class="formRight240" >');
htp.p('<input type="radio" name="p_status_c" id="sc1" value="A"/><label for="sc1">Active</label>');
htp.p('<input type="radio" name="p_status_c" id="sc2" value="I" /><label for="sc2">Inactive</label>');
htp.p('</div><div class="fix"></div>');
htp.p('</div>');
```

should be working, but is not, if you see the Java Script I am giving to the same radio button the style.visibility and is working, the only problem is when I try to change what radio button should be selected

pls help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is not working the radio buttons are not in DOM

Comment: DOM ?? how I create DOM radio buttons? do you have a link with an example?

Comment: its not DOM radio button. DOM means Document object model . are you sure that ur page has these radio buttons?

Comment: Yes, my form have the radio buttons .. this is not working neither, is this DOM ? document.cform.p_status_c[1].checked = true;

Comment: are you not getting selected value ?